# Need to group by the vehicle id from the online & offline date history logs and get the latest date of history

Tags: mysql

I have below the tables

1. tbl_vehicles

| vid | accnt_id | platenumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VD101 |
| 2 | 1 | VD102 |

2. tbl_status_history

| id | vid | accnt_id | date_online | date_offline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-25 | 0000-00-00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0000-00-00 | 2023-02-26 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0000-00-00 | 2023-02-27 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0000-00-00 | 2023-02-28 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0000-00-00 | 2023-03-01 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 0000-00-00 |

Now, I need to group the vid and get their latest status history. For example in vid:1 under tbl_status_history. This vid latest status history is online so the result for vid 1 would be the date_online 2023-03-02.

Below is my target result.

| id | vid | accnt_id | date_online | date_offline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 0000-00-00 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0000-00-00 | 2023-02-28 |

I used the code of  @nnichols and updated it to the below code to get also the latest online date but had still not worked out how to sort the two dates(Online & offline) before the group by

```
SELECT h.id, h.vid, h.accnt_id, h.date_online, h.date_offline, v.platenumber
FROM tbl_status_history h
JOIN (
    SELECT vid, MAX(date_offline) max_date_offline, MAX(date_online) max_date_online
    FROM tbl_status_history
    GROUP BY vid
) h2 ON h.vid = h2.vid AND h.date_offline = h2.max_date_offline and h.date_online = h2.max_date_online
JOIN tbl_vehicles v ON h.vid = v.vid and h.accnt_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to produce your *"target result"* using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT h.id, h.vid, h.accnt_id, h.date_online, h.date_offline, v.platenumber
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY GREATEST(date_online, date_offline) DESC) rn
    FROM tbl_status_history
    WHERE accnt_id = 1
) h
JOIN tbl_vehicles v ON h.vid = v.vid
WHERE h.rn = 1;
```

Or, the pre MySQL 8 method:

```
SELECT h.id, h.vid, h.accnt_id, h.date_online, h.date_offline, v.platenumber
FROM tbl_status_history h
JOIN (
    SELECT vid, GREATEST(MAX(date_offline), MAX(date_online)) max_date
    FROM tbl_status_history
    WHERE accnt_id = 1
    GROUP BY vid
) h2 ON h.vid = h2.vid AND (h.date_offline = h2.max_date OR h.date_online = h2.max_date)
JOIN tbl_vehicles v ON h.vid = v.vid;
```

You should consider changing the structure of `tbl_status_history` to:

| id | vid | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | online | 2023-02-25 |
| 2 | 1 | offline | 2023-02-26 |
| 3 | 2 | offline | 2023-02-27 |
| 4 | 2 | offline | 2023-02-28 |
| 5 | 1 | offline | 2023-03-01 |
| 6 | 1 | online | 2023-03-02 |

- `accnt_id` is in `tbl_vehicles`, where it belongs, so redundant here
- two `DATE` columns to store one `status change date` does not make sense
- you could drop `id` too, in favour of the natural key, bit I probably wouldn't go that far

Comment: What does h2 function in the query?

Comment: The `h2` [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) gets the maximum `date_offline` per group (`vid`), which is then joined back to the full row in `h`. Does that help you?

Comment: I tried to customize your query in order for me also to get the latest date_online but nothing works. ```JOIN (
    SELECT vid, MAX(date_offline) max_date_offline, MAX(date_online) max_date_online
    FROM tbl_status_history
    GROUP BY vid
) h2 ON h.vid = h2.vid AND h.date_offline = h2.max_date_offline and h.date_online = h2.max_date_online
JOIN tbl_vehicles v ON h.vid = v.vid and h.accnt_id = 1;```

Comment: I already updated my question and also updated the sample database.

Comment: I have updated the two queries. I think the `id`s in your _"target result"_ should be `6` and `4`, not `2` and `4`.

Comment: You really are great db engineer sir. Thank u!